# Oracle 10 xe; backing up oradata folder enough to recreate a duplicate later?

Tags: oracle

Let us say, I backup of the the oradata folder.

Is that enough to recreate the exact same database?

E.g., I reinstall oracle xe 10 on the same pc, using the same installer, into the same folder, and the replace its oradata folder with one i have?

And also is it the exact duplicate in terms of the database?

Answer (score 1):

List of files that you should backup:

```
select member from v$logfile;
select name from v$datafile;
select name from v$controlfile;
select value from v$parameter where name ='spfile';
```

If the last query returns nothing, backup `%ORACLE_HOME%/database/initXE.ora` (Windows) or `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/initXE.ora` (Linux, Unix).

To make it a simple as possible, you can simply copy these files after the database was shut down.

An online backup requires ARCHIVELOG mode configured and using user-managed backup from SQL*Plus combined with OS commands, or RMAN.

Answer (score 0):

I would go further than @Balazs and say that backing up your Oracle database should *always* be done using the Recovery MANager utility, **RMAN**.

Properly configured, *it knows* which files need to be backed up and can do so in a manner than *guarantees* they will be recoverable which is, after all, the whole point of the exercise.

Never go *anywhere near* the files of a running database [instance].

Once the database is safely shut down then *maybe* you can work with its files, but using RMAN is *always* preferable.